# React - fixed navbar and nav-tab

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am using `reactstrap` package in for my project. So, I have created a `HeaderComponent` which is a `Navbar` which is fixed at top `fixed=top`.

```
import React from 'react';
import Context from '../provider'
import {
    Collapse,
    Navbar, NavbarToggler, NavbarBrand, Nav, NavItem, NavLink,
    Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button,
} from 'reactstrap';
import LoginComponent from './LoginComponent'
import SignupComponent from './SignupComponent'

class HeaderComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Consumer>
                {context => {
                    return (
                        <Navbar color="light" light expand="md" fixed="top">
                            <NavbarBrand href="/">Reddit</NavbarBrand>
                                <NavbarToggler onClick={() => context.toggleNavbar()} />
                                <Collapse isOpen={context.navbarOpen} navbar>
                                <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                                    <NavItem><LoginComponent /></NavItem>
                                    <NavItem><SignupComponent /></NavItem>
                                </Nav>
                            </Collapse>
                        </Navbar>
                    )   
                }}
            </Context.Consumer>
        )
    }
}

export default HeaderComponent;
```

I also have a `TabComponent`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Context from '../../provider'
import {Nav, NavItem, NavLink} from 'reactstrap'
import classnames from 'classnames'

class TabComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Consumer>
                {context => (
                    <Nav tabs>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink
                                className={classnames({ active: context.activeTab === '1' })}
                                onClick={() => { context.toggleTab('1'); }}
                            >
                            Home
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink
                                className={classnames({ active: context.activeTab === '2' })}
                                onClick={() => { context.toggleTab('2'); }}
                            >
                            Popular
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink
                                className={classnames({ active: context.activeTab === '3' })}
                                onClick={() => { context.toggleTab('3'); }}
                            >
                            All
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>                
                    </Nav>
                )}
            </Context.Consumer>
        )
    }
}

export default TabComponent;
```

I am making the `HeaderComponent` **fixed** but I don't know how to make the `TabComponent` **fixed** below the `HeaderComponent`.

---

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51131778/8208804) answer, I did the following:

**TopComponent**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import HeaderComponent from './HeaderComponent'
import TabComponent from './TabComponent'
import {Row, Col, Container} from 'reactstrap'
import './style.css'

export default class TopComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='vert-align'>
                <Container>
                    <Row><Col><HeaderComponent /></Col></Row>
                    <Row><Col><TabComponent /></Col></Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**style.css**

```
.vert-align {
    top:0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:100;
}
```

They are now fixed to the top one below the other but, they are **not covering the complete width** of screen now!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest in my opinion would be to make a parent component `FixedTopComponent` for both `HeaderComponent` and `TabComponent`, and fix this one to the top `fixed=top`. then you just have to align the two children components vertically, using either bootstrap rows or `{display: flex; flex-direction: column}` in your css.

Here's an example:

```
class FixedTopComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const vert_align = {
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column'
        }
        <div id='fixed-top" style={vert_align} fixed='top'>
            <HeaderComponent />
            <TabComponent />
        </div>
    }
}
```

**Edit**: For your second issue (not sure cause I never used reactstrap), try:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import HeaderComponent from './HeaderComponent'
import TabComponent from './TabComponent'
import {Row, Col, Container} from 'reactstrap'
import './style.css'

export default class TopComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container fluid className='vert-align'>
                <Row><Col><HeaderComponent /></Col></Row>
                <Row><Col><TabComponent /></Col></Row>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. How can I solve the update that I made in question?

Comment: You're welcome. Look at my edited answer for your new issue. Also if this answer resolves your problem, could you accept it (green tick mark) ?

Comment: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `fluid`.

Comment: That's weird, according to this: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/layout/ it's supposed to be a Boolean attribute.  I don't really know reactstrap though, so unless you really need to make it work with bootstrap, you can just use flex like my first snippet

Comment: Ya it needs to be `<Container fluid className='vert-align'>`. Adding `fluid` makes the boolean **true**. Maybe add that to your answer! Thanks!